# What does it mean if someone refers to something as BootStrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I hear the term "BootStrap" thrown around a lot, but I'm not really sure what it refers to. I know there is a bootstrap CSS, but what exactly does the term mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Literally, a bootstrap is a tab on the sides or back of boots that helps you to pull them on. Putting on your shoes or boots is usually the last step of getting dressed; similarly, in programming it's been applied to the initialization or start-up step of a program.

See also the [Wikipedia entry for bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping):

> Bootstrapping or booting refers to a group of metaphors which refer to a self-sustaining process that proceeds without external help.
>
> [.. in Software Loading] booting is the process of starting a computer, specifically in regards to starting its software. The process involves a chain of stages, in which at each stage a smaller simpler program loads and then executes the larger more complicated program of the next stage. It is in this sense that the computer "pulls itself up by its bootstraps", i.e. it improves itself by its own efforts
>
> [.. in Software Development] bootstrapping can also refer to the development of successively more complex, faster programming environments. The simplest environment will be, perhaps, a very basic text editor (e.g., ed) and an assembler program. Using these tools, one can write a more complex text editor, and a simple compiler for a higher-level language and so on, until one can have a graphical IDE and an extremely high-level programming language.

A shoehorn is another means to help you don footwear but it's idiomatically come to mean cramming something into a tight space.

Answer (score 5):

In computer science Bootstrap (or more commonly "Boot") generally refers to the setup/start/initialization step of a process. It can mean many things depending on the context: starting a physical machine, setting up variables and services for an application to use, or even laying the css groundwork for a website to implement.

Comment: A rather broad definition. Given the [twitter] tag, the OP is probably referring to [twitter-bootstrap].

Comment: did you read the "even laying the css groundwork for a website to implement" part of the 2nd sentence...

Comment: Yup, I read that part of your answer. I also read the question. I maintain that it's a broad definition.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: I also read it as a request for general clarification of the word itself, and only incidentally mentioning Twitter Bootstrap as a known application of the term. However, I do agree it is a bit too broad: booting is "starting a physical machine" only by extension, but more specifically means running the bootloader: a basic functionality that allows more complex functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrapping let you create your own most **complex design by just minimal configuration**, rather than develop it from the scratch.